# Someone is copying SO,is SO licensed?

Tags: support

Hello,

There was a question on SO([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275611/i-want-to-do-a-chinese-version-of-stackoverflow-are-interested-please-join-the-di)) where the author linked us to his [chinese copy](http://www.cnprog.com/) of SO.

What is going to be done about that,is SO licensed?

Comment: The edits could have at least tried to parse intent instead of just copy-pasting from Google.

Answer (score 6):

That clone has been around for a few months. Although it initially used the CSS from Stack Overflow, it has subsequently been replaced and no longer represents copyright infringement.

Since they don't run our code and don't have any of our content, there's very little that needs to be "done" about them.

Comment: Maybe they'll end up as another member of the Justice League.

Comment: @Random I think they're missing the most important part. English.

Comment: There was also the Justice League Europe/International to belabour a metaphor.

Comment: I would not be surprised if Jeff decided to partner with CNProg instead of attempting to compete with it with a Chinese language SO site.

Comment: Hey,sorry for the late reply.I'd accept your answer if you assist,I wanted to check Jeff's responce.

Comment: You forgot .. COMMUNITY!!